# CakePHP image upload component

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I would like to know how I can improve this CakePHP 3.0 `Component` (inside folder controller)

**1st:** to use external libs (stored on vendor folder) I'm using the `require` keyword and include the class using `use` keyword, like this:

```
require_once(ROOT . DS . 'vendor' . DS . 'CakePHP-ImageTool-Component' . DS . 'ImageTool.php');
```

and

```
use ImageTool;
```

> How I can put this on CakePHP 3 pattern ?

**2nd:** in method `saveFileLFS` I'm using `true` or `false` to flag OK.

> How I can improve this check ?

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller\Component;

require_once(ROOT . DS . 'vendor' . DS . 'CakePHP-ImageTool-Component' . DS . 'ImageTool.php');

use Burzum\FileStorage\Lib\StorageManager;
use Cake\Controller\Component;
use ImageTool;

class UploadFileComponent extends Component
{
    function resizeImage($settings)
    {
        $status = ImageTool::resize([
            'input' => $settings['input'],
            'output' => $settings['output'],
            'width' => $settings['width'],
            'height' => $settings['height'],
            'mode' => $settings['mode']
        ]);
        return $status;
    }

    public function saveFileLFS($stringSeparator, $storeName, $productName)
    {
        $key = $storeName . $stringSeparator . $productName . $stringSeparator .
            $this->request->data['Media']['file']['name'];
        if(StorageManager::adapter('Local')->write($key,
            file_get_contents($this->request->data['Media']['file']['tmp_name']))){
            return true;
        }else
       {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @drmonkeyninja put the questions

Comment: You're trying to use 2 or 3 different plugins, using them in a wrong way plus mixing that with your own code and doing it in the wrong layer of the framework and not using composer for one of them. *Serious* recommendation: Start over with this task and do some research / reading before. A comment is not enough to explain everything in detail and honestly, I'm to lazy to give a free lesson for that amount "wrong doing" that is shown here. This is simply to much to get this covered in a reasonable short explanation. Actually FileStorage could do all you want - read the exhaustive documentation!